# Possible webview with menu buttons that load different urls?

Tags: ios, menu, webview

I am new to xcode development so hang in there with my lack of knowledge. (BTW i've searched for this already with no luck).

I have a webview app I am working on, I do not want the users using the onsite menu because it's not optimal for mobile yet. So I want to offer a menu on the app that loads up various in-site url's. I have created a menu and added the back and refresh buttons so I have gotten that far but cannot figure out how to get other buttons i've created (example "categories") to load example.com/categories and hope someone can help me as this will save me much frustration. The app is a single webview so i'm not sure if that plays a role in this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let say that your buttons trig the same function and you have set their tag, you could do :

```
-(IBAction)loadButton:(id)sender
{
    NSString *urlString;
    switch(((UIButton*)sender).tag)
    {
        case 1:
            urlString=@"http://www.exemple.com/categories";
            break;
        case 2:
        //...
    }
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
}
```